# Countable cartesian products

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What is a countable cartesian product of finite sets? That is, suppose $A_j$ are finite sets. Then what can you say about $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} A_j$? I know countable cartesian product of countably infinite set is uncountable. But i can not predict this.

Comment: Are you asking what the cardinality is of the cartesian product of countably many finite sets?

Comment: I think you are asking "What is the cardinality of..." rather than "What is..."?

Comment: Basically, each element is an infinitely tuple with each component having finitely many values. Very much like the "set of all binary strings". Does that give you an answer?

Comment: A different case is if the cardinality of $A_j$ is finite but unbounded. For example, $A_1 = \{1\},\ A_2 = \{1, 2\}, \ldots, A_n = \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}, \ldots$. This is *not* like the set of binary strings.

Comment: I am asking whether it is countable or not...

Answer (score 1):

If one of the sets is empty, the product is empty, and thus finite. If all but finitely many have just one element, then again the product is finite.

Assume that all sets have at least two elements, then the product $\prod_{n=1}^\infty\{0,1\}$ can be mapped injectively into the product of the $A_i$'s (by choosing each time two elements from each $A_i$).

(Note that if infinitely many sets have one element, and infinitely more have at least two, then we can prove as above that the product of the non-singletons is uncountable and trivially map it into the larger product.)

Comment: Is this true even in the case of the example I gave, where the number of elements a set can have, has no upper bound? $A_1 = \{1, 2\},\ A_2 = \{1, 2, 3\}, \ldots, A_n = \{1, 2, \ldots, n + 1\}, \ldots$ (I modified it so every set has at least two elements, although even otherwise, only one set is singleton).

Comment: Of course. As long none of them is empty, each of them has at least two elements (except one, which doesn't matter).

Comment: Oh, actually I see why this works. If the argument had been that the product was countable, *then* my example might have created a problem. For some reason, I was worried about a possible increase in the cardinality in the case of finite sets of unbounded size, forgetting that the product already is uncountable.